# Mouse & Keyboard freeze - nomodeset solved it but not sound

Tags: sound

fresh starter. no knowledge about linux.
installed ubuntu 20.04 on system and keyboard mouse freezes as soon as I get to login page(after 2-3 sec). After quick search, i added nomodeset(apparently you boot linux without graphics driver) in grub and was able to run the mouse and keyboard. No issues.

However, the other issue is i can not hear anything when i play sound. Went to sound section where output device is "Dummy output" is selected and cannot change it.

Appreciate if someone can help me. it would be encouraging for me to learn more about ubuntu.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I am having exact same issue with thinkpad x1 yoga gen 4? What model PC are you using?